# â€‹â€‹ Characters keep showing up on website, HTML definitely set to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, liquid

So I know this is problem to do with UTF-8 encoding, but it seems to only be affecting certain parts of our site and as far as I can tell, I'm positive that our site is set to UTC-8 correctly.

Basically, we keep getting the unwanted string of: **â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹** etc... showing up on pages around our site, but only certain ones with adhering to a specific page template.

(See: http://www.highgatecontinental.com/pages/terms and also http://www.highgatecontinental.com/pages/about 
+ http://www.highgatecontinental.com/pages/shipping)

As mentioned, these are all pages that share a common template, and also pull content / contain an **rte** div  - not sure if that has anything to do with it?

As far as I can tell, the rest of the website it completely fine and it only just started acting up. IF anyone could shed some light on what I'm missing I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: It seems that the HTML is correctly encoded. These spurious characters are introduced in the creation of the page.

Comment: I think the origin of this sequence is the [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) (U+200B). It might be in your template (maybe invisible, as you can probably tell). When you encode this character with UTF-8, then decode it with CP-1252 ("Windows Latin-1"), you get exactly "â€‹".

Comment: As mentioned by @lenz, you have a lot of `&acirc;&#128;&#139;` in your pages, due to successive encodings. Search and replace to the rescue. In those particular pages, you're also including full html, with `<html><body>` tags, which is useless.